# display field error message on .valid and .touched on child component

Tags: angular

I have this child component that is called from a few parent components. I don't want to tie the error messages to the parent but just be displayed in the child component. It is angular 5 btw

child.component.ts

```
              item_brand = new FormControl('',
               [Validators.required]);
              item_quantity=new FormControl('',
               [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,3})?$')]);
```

child.component.html

```
      <input formControlName="item_brand">
                     <div class="alert" *ngIf="!item_brand.valid && item_brand.touched">Enter brand name or NA</div>
```

it doesn't show any errors and the submit button the parent form doesn't get activated until brand name is entered but the error message doesn't display. If entered, the form does get processed correctly as well.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this below code.

```
<div *ngIf="item_brand.dirty && item_brand.errors && (item_brand.hasError('required') || item_brand.hasError('pattern'))">Enter brand name or NA</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work but just curious: how would hassError work with regular expression validation?

Comment: Your form control includes only 'required' validation

Comment: Yes, yes. I showed the required in the example. I have other controls that have custom validations with a name (e.g. dateBeforeToday) and reg expresion pattern with Validators.pattern. If your solution had worked for me, how would i have used hasError with the Validators.pattern?

Comment: Check it now Suresh